# Open the url in the current active browser

Tags: email, browser, hyperlink

How can I open an url in the current active browser which is been provided as a part of the mail

Example- I receive an email in my outlook.I am browsing also.If I click on the url provided in the email it must open in the current browser window which is open

Comment: this also has nothing to do with Javascript

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible with a URL. The handling of http: protocol is operating system dependent, and really shouldn't be messed with.

Comment: I guess it’s possible in Windows. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

My default browser is FlashPeak SlimBrowser and with this as my default browser it isn't a problem since this is what it does by default. I use SlimBrowser since the web site I work on is keyed to IE and SlimBrowser uses the IE Object with any of the automatic IE junk disabled. No question about popups since they don't happen unless I click on them.

The click interface in outlook is using the API to open the default browser window. The default browser determines how it is going to handle the request.